# Why AsyncResult returns NoneType after task is done?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, django-celery

**Problem**

AsyncResult returns NoneType for task after it is finished.

**Question**

How can I get celery task state after it is done?

**Description**

Below is a code of django view for getting celery task state. I use this view to query task progress from my client app. It works fine, until the task is done. Afterwards AsyncResult returns NoneType each time I call it for my task, and i get the following error:

*'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'*

```
# Celery configuration
celery = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker="amqp://")

# My django view for getting task state    
def GetTaskStatus(request):
    task = AsyncResult(request.body["taskid"], app=celery)
    if task.state == 'PENDING':
        data = {
            'state': task.state,
            'progress': task.info.get("progress", 0)
        }
    elif task.state != 'FAILURE':
        data = {
            'state': task.state,
            'progress': task.info.get("progress", 0)
        }
    else:
        data = {
            'state': task.state,
            'error': "something went wrong",
            'progress': task.info.get("progress", 0)
        }
    response = GetHttpResponseJSON(ResponseCode.OK, data)
    return response
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this issue?

Comment: i am getting same issue, whether you were able to solve this ?

Comment: Im sure i did, unfortunately it was so long ago I cant remember how... Sorry for not being more helpful.

Comment: @VinayKadalagi your task must return something. Let's say it returns a simple string: "this task has end". Well, here is your task result. If the task returns nothing you will have None and hence...NoneType.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a result backend. See [the tutorial](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results).

Comment: Both my worker and queue are configured with backend="amqp"